# Protocols and delegates are not working properly

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, protocols

I have had this random issue pop up in between me trying to work on something and now.. I have even tried reloading an old snapshot that I know 100% was working and I just cannot figure this crap out.

basicly I have a class and a view controller, the class is trying to pass some data over to the view controller, everything in the class works perfectly, all the data is their ready and waiting to be sent over to the view controller with the delegates and protocols that i have set up but when I debug the view controller it never evnters the protocol method that is in the view controller that I have created in the class. I dunno if this is a simple bug, oversight or something i am missing in my code, I will write my code down now, hopefully someone else can see what I am missing.

Class.h

```
//This passes data back to the VehicleSearchViewController
@protocol SearchViewParsedData <NSObject>
- (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array;
- (void)sendModArray:(NSArray *)array;
@end
//..
id <SearchViewParsedData> SearchViewdelegate;
//..
//Delegates that will be acessed inside EngineRequests for passing the data mack to the viewcontroller
@property (strong) id <SearchViewParsedData> SearchViewdelegate;
//..
```

class.m

```
@synthesize SearchViewdelegate;
//..
//TODO: add if statments in this method so you can pass the data to the right methods and Views
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    if ([methodName isEqualToString:@"GetMan"]) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISAMAN",@"T"];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
    [[self SearchViewdelegate]sendMan:filteredArray];
    }
//..
```

So thats my class, then over in my viewcontroller

viewcontroller.h

```
#import "myClass.h"
//..
@interface MyVewController : UITableViewController <SearchViewParsedData> {
//..
MyClass *myClassResponse;
//..
```

viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//..
engineResponses = [[EngineResponses alloc] init];
[engineResponses setSearchViewdelegate:self];
//..
}


#pragma - EngineResponses Reciver methods
- (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    MyFilterArray = array;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

This is driving me abit crazy. I am sure I have everything perfect, but its just never making it to viewcontroller.m -(void)sendManArray... if anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

This is the log that is being generated when I add in that nslog

```
NSLog(@"Checking filtered array %@ %@", [self SearchViewdelegate], filteredArray);
```

produces :

```
Checking filtered array (null) (
        {
        ISMAN = F;
        ISVAR = T;
        MAN = "BLAAA";
        MANID = 3;
    },
        {
        ISMAN = F;
        ISVAR = F;
        MAN = "BANG";
        MANID = 3;
    },
//etc
```

Comment: delegates are traditionally weak, _unsafe_unretained, or assign, not strong.  And is it possible that MyFilterArray is not alloc'd and init'd?

Comment: I am logging that filtered array and its showing the correct content in it.. but even if that was the case, shouldnt it still make it to my viewcontroller and just have null represented in that method...

Comment: What happens when you log like this:  NSLog(@"%@ %@", [self SearchViewdelegate], filteredArray);  ??  Given the symptoms you describe, I'd wager its <null> [an array]

Comment: where should I put that NSLog?, dont worry I figured out where to put it.. trying now.

Comment: okay.. weird. your right... it has (null) BUT after that I get the xml that I want.. but I dunno where its comming from.. i am trying to find it but its like its part of the same print out...

Comment: I have updated whats its logging.. you were completely right.. how do I deal with that?

Comment: Its weird because up till now, for about the past week or two this has been working perfectly fine.. who would it just stop like that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this is pretty crazy.. I have solved the error, its completely unrelated to my delegates declarations etc.

I was prompted by xcode to update my debugger last week, this ended up breaking my simulator, or at least xcode when trying to deploy to the simulator. Moving on I was unable to solve this issue, until today at least. I reverted back to my old debugger in the schemer settings so I went back to GDB from LLDB.. this fixed my simulator error and... my protocol delegates that were not working...

what the heck???!
Hopefully this solves someone elses problem.. what an absolute pain in the butt.

however now I am wondering why LLDB is causing these issues? if you can answer that ill give you the reputation points I have on offer :)

Comment: More than likely the issue was still your delegate declarations. Strong for delegates cannot be more wrong.

Comment: what should it be declared as then?

Comment: Weak. Strong will retain the variable.

Comment: I agree with sam. Delegates should be declared weak or __unsafe_unretained. Declaring a delegate as strong is setting you up for a retain cycle and a memory leak. That would not cause the problem you're describing though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to replace the **Class.m file** with following code

```
@synthesize SearchViewdelegate;
//..
//TODO: add if statments in this method so you can pass the data to the right methods and Views
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
     if ([methodName isEqualToString:@"GetMan"]) {
     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISAMAN",@"T"];
     NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

     NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
     [[self SearchViewdelegate]sendManArray:filteredArray];
}
```

//..

Rest all thing is correct but I think sendMan is not available (which is written in your code) and in ViewController call same method

**viewcontroller.m**

in `- (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array` replace with following method

```
 - (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array
 {
      NSLog(@"%@",array);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
[[self SearchViewdelegate]sendManufactureArray:filteredArray];
```

but your delegate method definition is

```
- (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array
```

Try calling

```
[[self SearchViewdelegate]sendManArray:filteredArray];
```

instead.

Comment: It's still a typo.  It says `sendMan`, not `sendManArray`

Comment: Agreed, it's still wrong... can you copy+paste the code? There's no point adding it if it's not the exact code you're running. A small difference can make or break code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably still have a typo there. To find it during compile time
you can (temporarily) change your protocol definition to:

```
@protocol SearchViewParsedData <NSObject>
- (void)sendModArray:(NSArray *)array;
@required
- (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array;
@end
```

Also try modifying your `- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser` a bit:

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    if ([methodName isEqualToString:@"GetMan"])
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISAMAN",@"T"];
        NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

        NSLog(@"%@", filteredArray);
        if (!self.SearchViewdelegate)
        {
            if ([self.searchViewdelegate respondsToSelector: @selector(sendManArray:)])
            {
                NSLog (@"ok, calling my delegate");
                [[self.searchViewdelegate] sendManArray:filteredArray];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog (@"my delegate doesn't implement sendManArray:");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog (@"i have no delegate");
        }  
    }
    //..
```

It's also not a good idea to for a property name to begin with capital
letter. Not an error but you really should consider renaming `SearchViewdelegate` to `searchViewdelegate`

You also didnt show us your `parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries` code, but you might consider changing:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

to:

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Comment: okay so I have implemented the if statement you have shown above, and I am getting the **my delegate doesn't implement sendManArray:** response... I have also switched my filtered array over to the suggested one above. I also added the @requiered, but nothing happened with that.

Comment: @C.Johns: o.k., now you know where the problem is. Since your posted code contains this typos my first guess is that your original code does, too. I'd check delegate method names char-by-char.

Comment: how do i implement sendManArray? I have initalized it in the .h like so **id <SearchViewParsedData> SearchViewdelegate;** and also @synthesized it.. what else can I do?

Comment: I have fixed up any differences in the names no I get no errors nothing.. its just not implementing properly.

Comment: Something really doesn't add up. All i can think of would be to also declare `- (void)sendManArray:(NSArray *)array` in `viewcontroller.h` though this shouldn't be the root of the problem.

Comment: yea, the weird thing here is that it was working perfectly fine, then apple prompted me to update my xcodes debugger. since then so much has been going wrong with xcode. anytime I try to run the simulator it crashes xcode, so i have to build to my phone etc.. I am thinking that maybe this is an extension of the problem I am having because it was working then all of a suddon stopped working..

Answer (score 0):

Your `EngineResponses` class is a delegate to a `NSXMLParser`. You try to send a message to your `SearchViewdelegate` (btw, what's up with that spelling?)from a `NSXMLParser` delegate method and the property is `nil`. So the only conclusion is that you are setting the property after you call the `parse` method on your `NSXMLParser`.

So my suggestion is to pass the delegate to your `init` method as a parameter and set the `SearchViewdelegate` property before you send the `[NSXLMParser parse]` message.